# Use uppercase db and schema name of postgreSQL + Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc

Using Spring MVC with JPA 2.1 and Hibernate. While using uppercase db and schema name in configuration files like mvc-config.xml with jpa configuration and hibernate.default_schema respectively are not working.

It is working fine when i use lowercase db and schema name for postgres and application but vice -versa do not work. Is there any solution so that I can still use uppercase db and schema name in my configuration file. Any Idea ? Please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

this is because Spring wraps names to doublequotes. if you want to work with objects called in UPPERCASE, rename them this way first. like `alter database test rename to "TEST";`